# Extruded Part disappears after switching from Edit Mode into Object Mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

As the title says: my newly added parts in my mesh disappear when I change from edit into object mode.

And if I change the position of my mesh in edit mode it's still at the same spot in object mode.

My mesh is rigged and weight painted, I also made a few animations.

I already checked my layers, tried <kbd>Alt+H</kbd> but nothing helped. Making a new mesh wouldn't be a big deal, but I can't make always a new mesh if get the same problem, so I want to know how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: could you upload the blend file as well please? Use:  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this problem but I know it has to do something with the rigging and  animation

Comment: I just downloaded the blend file you uploaded to pasteall.org and I don't see the big extruded object either in object mode or in edit mode. Did you upload the correct file?

Comment: Bizarre, I see what you mean: I just extruded that same face and the extrusion disappears for some reason after switching out of edit mode. I wonder if you have to set a keyframe for the extrusion in the beginning of the animation? It might be that the size & shape of objects need to have keyframes also.

Comment: @BLendedUser If you need the shape keys, then at least you now will know what to research: how to edit Shape Keys to include edits to your model.

Comment: Thanks Thom Blair III and Vader, now i have some clues what i need to google :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Shape Keys**

I just deleted the Shape Keys for Head_Cube.005 and now the extruded arm face stays throughout the animation:

[image]

I don't know any more about Shape Keys, but here is a link to them on the Blender wiki:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Special:Search?search=shape+keys&fulltext=

If you need the shape keys, then you will need to figure out how to edit them to incorporate the extrusion throughout the animation. I'd help more with them if I could, but I know nothing else about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thom ! :) Guess i can live without them till i learn more about blender.

Comment: @BlendedUser No problem...I know the feeling! 
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to extrude on a model that has shape keys you must make sure you have  Basis selected before you do any edits. If you have any other shape key highlighted the edits will only show up for that shape key when it is set to 1.